# CakePHP not updating full array in database

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, save

Using CakePHP 3.5

For some reason, some of the elements in an array are being skipped when updating a row in the database.
This is the id: 4602006208571 that is being skipped.

Returning the save() function it returns the correct entity that is supposed to get updated, however, that is not the case.
If I add more numbers to the array it will update the field with the new entries except for 4602006208571.

Also $entity->errors() returns an empty array, and I am setting the field as dirty just in case.

```
$product_ids=array("4602406208572","4632006208572","4602006208572","4602006208571","4589010649147","4589010649148","4589010649159", "4599010649148");
$label->setDirty('product_ids', true);

$product_data = json_encode(array_values($product_ids), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
//Tried with json_encode($product_ids);

$label->product_ids = $product_data;
$label->date_modified = Time::now();

$this->Labels->save($label);
```

Hopefully someone has an idea what might the reason be.

Comment: So, your `$label->product_ids` field is a JSON-encoded string, and if you look at that string before saving, it's got all the numbers you want in it, but when you try to save it doesn't take the update? But if you have different numbers in the list, then it saves okay? That's truly baffling. Does `$label->errors()` have anything after the save? Does your error log have anything? If the string is quite different before saving, does it get updated with all the numbers except this one, or does it not get updated at all?

Comment: Exactly that is the case. No errors in the $label->errors() as well. I set the string to an empty one, it got updated. Added all the numbers back, only that specific number is missing. I tried moving it to different positions in the array, still not showing.

Comment: Some custom thing in your rules or `beforeSave` or the like? Some trigger in the database doing something with it? What you've shown here is clearly fine, so the problem will be elsewhere.